# How can I clip a multiband raster and preserve the band names?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3, clip, multi-band

I have a Landsat 8 image which I clipped with a polygon shapefile. It works fine, but I'd like to preserve each band name in order to improve my workflow speed. The output raster saves each band as "clip1", "clip2"... and so on, what I'm looking for is something like "Blue", "Green", etc.

I'm working with ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

The "Make Feature Layer" tool worked great to complete the task. Although its output is a temporal raster, just right clicking and then exporting the data was enough.